# PCI DSS 3.1 and Windows XP

Tags: tls, pci-dss

I'm looking for some clarification on the effects of PCI DSS v3.1.

In an consumer ecommerce context (e.g amazon.com), I'm assuming that customers attempting to make credit card purchases on the site, using Windows XP, would no longer be supported, due to the removal of TLS 1.0 as an acceptable protocol version. Is this correct?

Comment: I think the protocol has more to do with the browser than OS. I suspect Chrome on XP is fine.

Comment: Agreed - I'm working on the basis that by default, many XP users are likely to have stayed with the OS default browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users of **Windows XP with IE** will be unable to purchase from PCI-compliant vendors on the Internet after DSS v3.1's prohibition of TLS 1.0 takes place by June of 2016.  (Most merchants will turn off TLS v1.0 somewhere *before* that to be compliant without a last-minute rush).

Of course, if they wish to use Chrome, Firefox, Opera, or any other modern browser under Windows XP, they will be continue to be able to make purchases.  Here's an [excellent table of supported protocols by OS/Client by Qualys](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html).

It's the combination of an unsupported browser on an unsupported OS that's killing the XP+IE combo.

Answer (score 0):

They can use windows XP provided they use a browser that doesn't use the Windows SSL/TLS stack.

Chrome and Firefox use their own SSL/TLS stacks so they will continue to work. Internet Explorer uses the operating systems TLS stack so it will not work. I have not investigated other browsers or non-browser client applications but I would expect at least some of them to have problems.

It might be an idea to start doing some user agent sniffing to detect IE/XP users and push them towards firefox/chrome (ideally you would get them to upgrade their OS but that may be a bridge too far for many of them)